# Space between div and table

Tags: html, css, html-table, spacing

I have inherited this website and have finished coding this menu in div tags. Was formerly in a table. Now, however, the table below (out side of the container div I created) is hugely spaced. There isn't any sort of HTML element there causing the space.... So I am lost. I added 0 margins to my divs and got no where. Any suggestions? See: http://www.chinesemirch.com/foodTruck.htm

I am not the best at code, so any help is great.

Comment: (didnt downvote) but you need to post some relevant code. Try giving us an example using jsfiddle.net. Welcome to SO!

Comment: "hugely spaced"? Are you talking about how the main content cell of the page is small compared to the screen size? If so take a look at the table definition for it where there's a width attribute and height attributes on the `tr` children elements

Comment: We can help, but need to know your situation and goals in more precise language. What do you want it to look like? If there are several things you need to figure out, try asking one question at a time.

Comment: You can use the chrome dev tools  to work out where the space is.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the gap between your menu and the block of content below it, your outer table that contains the menu has css `margin-bottom:15px;`

Answer (score 0):

After reading your code I analyse that you have used "margin-bottom: 15px" in your table's style which is the reason of the extra space generated at the bottom.

> In future if you get extra gaps generated then recheck your code because most of the time it is because of wrong use of "margin" and "padding".